# Cannot send email in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am trying to send an email with Laravel 5.2. This is my first time of sending email in Laravel. But it is throwing this error

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 162: Cannot send message without a sender address
```

This is my code of sending email:

```
Route::get('test',function(){
    $message  = "hello";
    Mail::send('welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
    {

       $message->to('iljimae.ic@gmail.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
});
```

This is my email settings in env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=iljimae.ic@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

My welcome view only has a message "Hello world"

I already configured less secure app settings for my email in Gmail settings. So, what is wrong with my code, and why is that throwing that error?

Comment: The message is very clear! `Cannot send message without a sender address`. So you must set a sender: `$message->from('myMail@test.test')->to(...)`

Comment: But how to set password for from please ?

Comment: You already set the password in the env file.. it should work..

Comment: It throws this error again. Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. qj8sm2726219pac.40 - gsmtp
"

Comment: Try adding `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` ass mail_host in the env file

Comment: It says . Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.gmail.com

Comment: remove the ssl part and add `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: Thanks so much, It worked . Please post answer . I am gonna upvote yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `Cannot send message without a sender address` is clear. You just need to add `from` to the message:

```
Route::get('test',function(){
    $message  = "hello";
    Mail::send('welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
    {

       $message->from('myEmail@test.com')
           ->to('iljimae.ic@gmail.com', 'John Smith')
           ->subject('Welcome!');
    });
});
```

In order to be able to send the mail you must to change the mail encryption in the .env file to:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $message chain has 'To' and 'Subject' fields but is missing 'From' field.

Just add ->from() to the chain:

```
$message->to('iljimae.ic@gmail.com', 'John Smith')
    ->subject('Welcome!')
    ->from(Config::get('mail.from.address'), Config::get('mail.from.name'));
```

Assuming that 'from' is set in your config/mail.php file (where it may refer or may not refer to environment variables). If it's not, you could just specify it directly:

```
$message->to('iljimae.ic@gmail.com', 'John Smith')
    ->subject('Welcome!')
    ->from('iljimae.ic@gmail.com', 'John Smith');
```

Comment: Throwing this error. Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. tb10sm2833049pab.22 - gsmtp
"

Comment: This is an error from SMTP, not from Laravel. Your MAIL_ENCRYPTION is set to null in .env file, try setting it to 'tls'

Answer (score -1):

If your mail was not being sent, make sure to delete this parameter "MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null" from your .env file. This worked for me.